# 'bash: ifconfig: command not found' occurs when I'm using scp in CentOS7

Tags: bash, scp

While I'm using scp following error occurs:

```
$ scp -i key.pem a.tar.gz kaseton@172.168.2.130:.
bash: ifconfig: command not found
a.tar.gz                                 100%   25MB 147.0MB/s   00:00
$ type scp
scp is hashed (/usr/bin/scp)
```

File was sent successfully but this error irritates me. net-tools have already been set as in guide but it made no change. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24839810/ifconfig-command-not-found)

I'm using CentOS on VMware and the ip 172.168.2.130 is same machine.

Any ideas?

Comment: this thread: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/bash-scp-command-not-found-920513/ says the solution is to install openssh-clients, specifically it's the solution for centos

Comment: What is the output of `which ifconfig`? Looks like either this program is not installed or missing in your `$PATH`

Comment: @gal242 ifconfig is in /usr/sbin and it's already on path. :( ifconfig works well when I execute it on shell.

Comment: @Narzard already installed. :(